# How to perform calculation with values of dynamic input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a little problem with my html form code...

In my code, there are few input fields which are generated dynamically. In every input field generated dynamically, there is some numerical value. i need to do some Mathematical calculation with them.

="PE+ROCE+(2-SG)-(4-DY/2)"

This is a pattern of my calculation.  In this, PE, ROCE etc are the IDs of Dynamic Input fields generated.

Using values of dynamic input fields generated, I need to perform above calculation.
This calculation has to be executed when the user would click on "Calculate" Input Button. 
Then, the final calculated value from the above will be shown in the Output Tag present in bottom of my form code. 
I tried to solve this problem on my own. But unfortunately,  failed in this task.

somebody can now please help me to solve this problem.
I will be very grateful...

here is my full code of form..

```js
    // define the headings here, so we can access it globally
    // in the app
    let headings = []

    // appending the created HTML string to the DOM
    function initInputs(headingList) {
      jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
    }

    // the HTMLT template that is going to be appended
    // to the DOM
    function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
      let html = ''
      headingList.forEach(heading => {
        if (heading !== 'Company') {
          html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
          html += `<input id="${heading}">`
          html += '<br>'
        }
      })

      return html
    }

    // receiving data
    // this data arrives later in the app's lifecycle,
    // so it's the best to return a Promise object
    // that gets resolved (check JS Promise for more information)
    function getJSON() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
          resolve(JSON.parse(data))
        });
      })
    }

    // processing raw JSON data
    function processRawData(data) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        const companyData = []
        // creating data array
        // handling multiple sheets
        Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
          sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
            companyData.push({ ...company
            })
            // create headings only once
            if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
              Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
                headings.push(item.trim())
              })
            }
          })
        })
        resolve(companyData)
      })
    }

    $(async function() {

      let lists = [];

      function initAutocomplete(list) {
        const thisKey = 'Company'
        $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
          response(
            list.filter(item => {
              if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
                item.label = item[thisKey]
                return item
              }
            })
          )
        })
      }

      $("#company").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: lists,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
          // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
          $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
          return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          // handling n number of fields / columns
          headings.forEach(heading => {
            $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
          })
          return false;
        }
      });

      // starting data download, processing and usage
      getJSON()
        .then(json => {
          return processRawData(json)
        })
        .then(data => {
          // just so we see what data we are using
          console.log(data)
          // make the processed data accessible globally
          lists = data
          initAutocomplete(lists)
          initInputs(headings)
        })

    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <form id="frm1">
        <label for="company">Company: </label>
        <input id="company"><br />
        <div class="fields"></div>

<input type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
   
<p>Final Amount <output name="amount" for="calculation">0</output></p>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: in what part of your code you are doing `"A+B+(6-C)+(2-D/3)"`?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - You have not described how to recreate the issue and the autocomplete code confuses the issues

Comment: madalinivascu  I am doing this calculation with my dynamic input field values. Instead of A, B, C, D,  Values of Input fields will come. I have just used this as to show you pattern of Calculation. Thanks.

Comment: Where? When? What does the user have to do to see this calculation and where is your attempt? Is this not just an issue of delegation? Also why not use jQuery when you have it already?

Comment: This calculation will be executed when user clicks "Calculate" Button. I tried it to solve on my own. But failed in this.  Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: can u check my answer, isn't it solving ur issue?

Comment: Suryapratap Singh... I just tried to use your answer and your answer worked like a charm... Thankyou very much for your help and efforts. I tried to mark both of the answers as final solution. But unfortunately,  I think we can mark solution to only one.  And I am sorry.  I am replying to your great answer very late.

Comment: Can you please restore your answer.... It was very important for me.  I really appreciate your help and efforts. I am thankful for this

Comment: Yes,  it is a great thing that I was able to solve my problem because of just your and Ravi Patel efforts. I had tried to use your answer in my code. In Stack overflow,  it was working smoothly.  But in my phone, it was not working properly. I thought it is a temporary issue.  But when I again tried your answer after few hours,  your answer worked without any problem.  Please,  don't let me wrong. Hope you understand. And please,  can you restore your answer

Comment: the fact is, u did not even tried the answer earlier, it was always working, and i did ask wht is issue on phn, u did nt even reply, it looked clearly as if u already decided what is correct and somehow solved and accepted.....every one can read comments right, and pls leave now.

Comment: Sorry if you got hearted... But Honestly, I had checked your answer and also had replied to your answer about this issue through comment box. Sorry again if you got hearted 

Comment: Sorry suryapratap... But I am saying honestly,  I had replied... But maybe it could be my phone fault or maybe weak internet connection,  which interrupted in comment posting.... I know it is just a waste of time now to speak and discuss about such things. But believe me, I had wrote a comment. I never try to hurt someone's hard work and efforts.... Believe me brother...

Comment: sorry brother for what all happened till now. But can you please restore your answer. It was quite useful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try each loop of inputs

```
 $("#Calculate").click(function(){
        var peVal,roceVal,sgVal,dyVal;
    jQuery(".fields input").each(function (){
        var idHeading=$(this).attr("id");

        if(idHeading=="Your ID for PE input"){
            peVal=parseInt($(this).val());
        }

        if(idHeading=="Your ID for ROCE input "){
            roceVal=parseInt($(this).val());
        }

        if(idHeading=="Your ID for SG input"){
            sgVal=parseInt($(this).val());
        }

        if(idHeading=="Your ID for DY input"){
            dyVal=parseInt($(this).val());
        }

    });
    var output=peVal+roceVal+(2-sgVal)-(4-dyVal/2);
});
```

Comment: Still issues? Just fixed.

Comment: just fixed Typos. Please look at it now.

Comment: Ravi Patel thanks for your answer... I just tried to use your answer but I think there is some problem. Code is not working properly. Can you please check it here "https://jsfiddle.net/ywqmo2zu/3/"

Comment: You would need to do it on button . Input submit will redirect to the action.

Comment: I tried your JS fiddle,  but it is showing only NaN value. Can you please resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you enter values which is uncountable using given formula it throws NaN. I tried values PE-10, DY-1, ROCE-10,SG - 1.

Comment: @Ravi the values are in string format, u need to parse to do any calculation

Comment: Now this is working as I wanted.. But can you please add one more thing in your code. I need to display result value upto 2 decimal numbers.

Comment: Just replace parseInt with parseFloat. And try.

Comment: like this. https://jsfiddle.net/re6m0sf5/4/.                           toFixed is to limit it to 2 decimal point.

Comment: Ravi Patel,  can you please check why it is not working here.."https://code.sololearn.com/WDvn2B98xMkA/?ref=app"..... Thanks in advance

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Cal").click(function(){
var peVal=0,roceVal=0,sgVal=0,dyVal=0;
jQuery(".fields input").each(function (){ var idHeading=$(this).attr("id");  if(idHeading=="PE"){ peVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } if(idHeading=="ROCE"){ roceVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } if(idHeading=="SG"){ sgVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } if(idHeading=="DY"){ dyVal=parseInt($(this).val()); } }); 
var output=peVal+roceVal+(2-sgVal)-(4-dyVal/2);

$("output[name='amount']").text(output);
 }); 
});`

Comment: Thankyou very much Ravi Patel.. Finally got a proper answer... Just because of your help... Again thanks..

Comment: Ravi Patel can you please solve my this problem.... If user enters negative values in input fields,  my calculation function/code is displaying a wrong amount. But  If I set default values for these inputs and use them only when user enters negative or zero values in Dynamic input fields, code would start behaving properly. Can you please solve my this little problem. I will be very grateful... Please...

Comment: can you give me example values?